# How to transform solution of Ryacas into character string?

Tags: r, symbolic-math

I want to get out the solution Ryacas gives me as a character string - but it doesn't work:

```
> require("Ryacas")
> x <- Sym("x")
> expr <- Solve(x + 1 == 0, x)
> expr
expression(list(x == -1))
> as.character(expr)
[1] "( Solve( ( ( x + 1 ) == 0 ) , x ) )"
```

Strangely enough when I print the variable I get the *solution* but when I try to read it out as a string I get the *original equation*.

**My question**
How can I transform the *solution* of Ryacas into a character string? (So that I can modify it further with standard R?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get that expression into a string, you should use `Eval()` to get the results of evaluation

```
Eval(expr)
# [[1]]
# expression(x == -1)
```

if you want to extract the result as a character, in this case you can do

```
Eval(expr)[[1]][[1]]
# [1] "( x == -1 )"
```

Comment: I just found out that you could also use as.character(Eval(expr))

Comment: I also found out another thing: If the solution is a fraction the above solution will only give the decimal solution. Do you know whether it is also possible to retrieve the (more exact) fraction? Thank you again!

Comment: This is what I mean:> expr
expression(list(x == 108/61))
> Eval(expr)[[1]][[1]]
[1] "( x == 1.77049180327869 )"

Comment: Maybe something like `as.character(yacas(unclass(expr))[[1]])`